# Starting Stopping a service with two different script Windows

Tags: windows-7, services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a jJava application that I need to start and stop using two different scripts (or a single script with two parameters).

In Linux I would simply put a script in `/etc/init.d/` directory or something similar dipending on the distro.

But how can I achieve the same behaviour in Windows (in particulary windows server 2012 r2)?

Comment: you seem to want it to act as a service. is there any reason for that? is it supposed to start automatically at boot? otherwise I'm not sure why you can't just treat it as any other application, launching it when you need it, and ending it when you don't.

Comment: The reason that I want the application as a service is that: 1. I want the it to run even if no user is logged, 2. I want run in background.

Comment: Then it sounds like the easiest way is to use the windows task scheduler. you can start or stop the task from the scheduler, set it to run non-interactively, and to do so under whatever user account, without a login. if you really want to register it as a service you can try this: http://mscrm-developer.blogspot.com/2009/05/registering-net-windows-service-script.html but I wonder if windows can really handle a java service, since the Java code is not the executable (java.exe is).